# SwiftUI 3: automatic keyboard avoidance for TextField in a ScrollView doesn't include padding

Tags: ios, swiftui

The automatic keyboard avoidance feature in (`SwiftUI 3`) doesn't move `TextField` up correctly if that `TextField` has a padding around and is inside a `ScrollView`.

Here is the code and result when the `TextField` is inside a `ScrollView`:

```
ScrollView {
        VStack {
              Rectangle().frame(height: 370)
               Spacer()
                  
               Group {
                   TextField("enter text", text: $myText)
                }
                 .padding()
                 .background(Color.gray)
                    
                }
          }
```

[image]

and here's the code and result when the `TextField` is NOT inside the `ScroolView`:

```
VStack {
                    Spacer()
                  
                    Group {
                        TextField("enter text", text: $myText)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray)
                }
```

[image]

is there a way to move the `TextField` extra space up when it's inside a `ScrollView` ?

Comment: I have filed a bug to Apple `FB10020371 `

Comment: Hey! Do you have any news/updates? Or maybe you solved it with another solution? Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderKhitev I filed a bug to Apple before 6 months, but there's no update from their side until now, I tried the code on XCode 14 and iOS 16.1 there is no change, the bug still there